# dynamically generated inputs with buttons don't get an onclick

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic, onclick, toggle

I would like to create a form which allows additional inputs to be added dynamically and each line of the input has a button which when clicked should expose additional inputs which are optional.

Regrettably, I can't seem to create an onclick handler for the dynamically generated button that will do anything

Thank you for any clues

[Here is a fiddle which demonstrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/slashdottir/BTS4A/)

Here is the same code as in the fiddle:

**css and javascript:...**

```
<style>
#time_est_input {
    display: none
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button-time-est").click(function () {
        $("#time_est_input").toggle();
    });
});
var g_ = new Object();
g_.counter = 1;

function addAnotherItem() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.title = "item";
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "item" + g_.counter.toString();
    input.value = "";

    var inputCat = document.createElement("input");
    inputCat.title = "category";
    inputCat.type = "text";
    inputCat.id = "category" + g_.counter.toString();
    inputCat.value = "";

    var tesid = "time_est_input" + g_.counter.toString();

    var timeEstSpan = document.createElement("span");
    timeEstSpan.id = tesid;
    timeEstSpan.style.cssText = "display:none;";

    var timeEstButton = document.createElement("input");
    timeEstButton.title = "Add Time Estimate";
    timeEstButton.type = "button";
    timeEstButton.value = "+";
    timeEstButton.id = "time_est_button" + g_.counter.toString();
    timeEstButton.setAttribute("myspan", tesid);
    timeEstButton.onClick= function() {
        var tesid = this.getAttribute('myspan');
        var myspan = $(tesid);
        myspan.toggle();
    }; 

    var inputTimeEst = document.createElement("input");
    inputTimeEst.title = "time estimate";
    inputTimeEst.type = "text";
    inputTimeEst.id = "time_est" + g_.counter.toString();
    inputTimeEst.value = "";

    timeEstSpan.appendChild(inputTimeEst);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    $('#form_list_parent').append(input);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(inputCat);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(timeEstButton);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(timeEstSpan);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(br);
    $(input).focus();

    g_.counter += 1;
}
</script>
```

**Html:...**

```
Desired behavior:<br>
<input type=text id="item" title="item" autofocus></input>
<input type=text id="category" title="category"></input>
<input title="add time estimate" type="button" id="button-time-est" value="+"> 
<span id="time_est_input">
   <input type='text' id='time_est' title="time estimate"/>
</span>
<hr/>
    Dynamically generated inputs with buttons don't behave as above:<br>
        <p id="form_list_parent"></p>
        <input type="button" id="additembutton" value="add item"     onclick="addAnotherItem()" />
        <br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, without changing of your html structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "body" ).on( "click", "input[id^='time_est_button']", function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
});   
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/BTS4A/10/**

Edit: As suggested, better use class for this, if you don't need unique (incremented) id.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', "#button-time-est", function () {
    $("#time_est_input").toggle();
});
```

You can improve performance marginally by using your form or some other ancestor that's available on load as a selector instead of `document`.

https://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this technique.  No help.  If you can modify the fiddle in a way that demonstrates your solution - that would help.

Comment: This solution is identical to your accepted answer aside from the particular selectors.

Comment: I suppose so, when I tried it didn't work.  The other guy provided a fiddle that demonstrated its functionality.  So I accepted his answer.  Best wishes.